# Multibranched fluorinated thiol IUPAC name

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I've been reading some papers about using self-assembled monolayers as hydrophobic coatings and came across this molecule:
[image]

Throughout the entire article its simply referred to as "multibranched fluorinated thiol" and I was wondering if anyone knew what the proper IUPAC name for it might be? Here is the DOI to the journal article in case anyone is interested in it:

[10.1021/acssuschemeng.8b00777](https://doi.org/10.1021/acssuschemeng.8b00777)

Comment: What IUPAC name, PIN?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already correctly identified the principal characteristic group of the compound as thiol. Thus, the parent structure is **propane-1-thiol.**

Next you can add the neopentyl ether group and get **3-(2,2-dimethylpropoxy)propane-1-thiol.**

The fluorinated *tert*-butyl groups are named **1,1,1,3,3,3-hexafluoro-2-(trifluoromethyl)propan-2-yl.** Including the ether group, these substituents are **[1,1,1,3,3,3-hexafluoro-2-(trifluoromethyl)propan-2-yl]oxy.**

Adding three of these substituents gives the complete name **3-[3-{[1,1,1,3,3,3-hexafluoro-2-(trifluoromethyl)propan-2-yl]oxy}-2,2-bis({[1,1,1,3,3,3-hexafluoro-2-(trifluoromethyl)propan-2-yl]oxy}methyl)propoxy]propane-1-thiol.**

Comment: That's a hell of a mouthful as a systematic name. Surely with something this symmetric there must be some neat *simple* but non-systematic name? It could be seen as a derivative of pentaerythritol, surely? Please. ;-)

Comment: My organic tutor would have said something like "Just call it Fred's compound". Change Fred as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @Loong, that really is quite the mouthful! I can see why they decided to go with multibranched fluorinated thiol instead of giving the full name.